# Log4cplus char* and tstring issue with FileAppender

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I have two projects with almost the same configuration in visual studio 2010
One with the console works and gives no trouble with the statement

```
SharedAppenderPtr myAppender(new FileAppender("myLogFile.log"));
```

While the other project a dll project gives trouble with the same statement

```
SharedAppenderPtr myAppender(new FileAppender("myLogFile.log"));
```

The error message is:

> > Error 3   error C2664: 'log4cplus::FileAppender::FileAppender(const log4cplus::tstring &,std::ios_base::openmode,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'const log4cplus::tstring &'

Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `"myLogFile.log"` like this: `LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("myLogFile.log")`. You could also use the `_T()` macro, since you are on Windows with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type `log4cplus::tstring` is but assuming it is a `typedef` for a type similar to `std::basic_string<cT>` (possibly even `std::basic_string<cT>` with a type `cT` other than `char`) you might try one of these:

```
SharedAppenderPtr app1(new FileAppender(L"myLogFile.log"));
std::string name("myLogFile.log");
SharedApppenderPtr app2(new FileAppender(log4cplus::tstring(name.begin(), name.end())));
```